# how do you configure `celery` to use serializer 'pickle'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, celery, kombu

on the tasks.py side i do:

```
app = Celery(
        main='tasks',
        backend='rpc://',
        broker='pyamqp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost',
        )
app.conf.task_serializer = 'pickle'
app.conf.result_serializer = 'pickle'
app.conf.event_serializer = 'pickle'
app.conf.accept_content = ['pickle']
app.conf.task_accept_content = ['pickle']
app.conf.result_accept_content = ['pickle']
app.conf.event_accept_content = ['pickle']
```

when i start two workers manually i via:

```
celery --app tasks worker --concurrency=1 -n by_hand_1 &
sleep 5
celery --app tasks worker --concurrency=1 -n by_hand_2
```

i get errors:

```
[ERROR/MainProcess] Refusing to deserialize disabled content of type pickle (application/x-python-serialize
```

### how do you configure `celery` to use serializer 'pickle'?

p.s. regarding "duplicates" the `celery` framework has changed significantly and since version 4.0 the default serializer was changed from `pickle` to default `json`... so that is why i am asking a new question.

Comment: What is the Celery version you used when you got this error?

Comment: @DejanLekic python 3.6, centos 7.9, celery==5.1.2, kombu==5.1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

configuring the app with the MIME type seems to fix the issue:

```
app.conf.event_serializer = 'pickle' # this event_serializer is optional. somehow i missed this when writing this solution and it still worked without.
app.conf.task_serializer = 'pickle'
app.conf.result_serializer = 'pickle'
app.conf.accept_content = ['application/json', 'application/x-python-serialize']
```

previously i was trying to set the accept conect field with just 'pickle' which did not help.

p.s. here are some more notes regarding if you need the pickle serializer:

- if you need to send json-non-serializable objects then you also need to configure the task serializer with 'pickle'
- if your results have json-non-serializable objects then you need to configure the result serializer to 'pickle'
- setting the `accept_content` to the value above means you can send both `json` and `pickle` and `celery` will see the type in the message headers and do the right thing