# Scrapy Spider Error : Can't pickle local object 'Crawler.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'

Tags: python, scrapy, celery

I would like to run Scrapy spiders(version **2.10**) within a Celery(version **5.3.4**) task. Additionally, I would like my spider to work using multiprocessing.
I have defined a CrawlerProcess class as follows:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from multiprocessing import Process
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy import signals, crawler

class CrawlerProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self, spider_cls, args):
        Process.__init__(self)
        settings = get_project_settings()
        self.crawler = Crawler(spider_cls, settings)
        self.crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        self.args = args
```

Externally, I have defined a Celery task as follows:

```
from aifc import Error

from kombu import Queue
from scrapy import crawler
from twisted.internet import reactor

from celery import Celery
from celery import states
import time


app = Celery("run")
app.config_from_object("scrapyselenium.celery_config")
app.conf.task_queues = (Queue(name='default'))

@app.task(bind=True, name="defaultTask", queue="default")
def scraper(self, args):
    self.update_state(state=states.STARTED)
    crawler = None
    try:

        crawler = CrawlerProcess(SiteMonitorSpider, args)
        self.update_state(state=states.PENDING)
        crawler.start()
        crawler.join()
        self.update_state(state=states.SUCCESS)
        return args
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        self.update_state(state=states.REVOKED)
        if crawler is not None:
            crawler.terminate()
            crawler.close()
```

However, when I start the Celery task, I get the following error: "Can't pickle local object 'Crawler.init.<locals>.<lambda>'."

Could you please tell me how to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to post as the answer, but I think the problem is with `Process.__init__(self)` as the `self` parameter is assumed, so you are actually passing your CrawlerProcess instance into `__init__` function as the first positional parameter after self, which is `group`.   So I think it should be `Process.__init__()` or `super().__init__()`

Answer (score 0):

Celery serialises function `args` and `kwargs` while sending them through the broker. So it expects every `arg/kwarg` to be either `pickle` or `json` serialisable depending on serialiser you use. By default, `json` is used in latest versions. Try changing the serialiser to `pickle` like [follows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69546952/10789204) and see if it works. If it doesn't, you can pass simple serialisable objects over the broker.