# How do I stop celery from converting my custom classes into dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, class, celery, pickle

I have a class instance I am trying to pass over to celery task, However when I do so celery converts it to a class dict.
I need to the instance to remain the instance and not get converted into a dict. The class is used for our config attributes. It allows us to reference attributes in nested instances so I dont need to use python's dict referencing.

Instead of having to reference an attribute like this:
`config["project"]["attr"]["thing"]`
I can reference it like this
`config.project.attr.thing`

I have read about how Celery does this because of its serializer. I tried setting the following, but it didn't change anything. What actually happened was it wouldn't accept any content as if it didn't know what `['pickle']` was.

```
task_serializer = 'pickle'
result_serializer = 'pickle'
accept_content = ['pickle']
```

I also read this post, but it did not help: [how do you configure `celery` to use serializer 'pickle'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531560/how-do-you-configure-celery-to-use-serializer-pickle)

How can I stop celery from messing with my class instances as input?

Comment: I dont know but I cant add this link to my post, adding it here, its the "this post" part of my question above
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531560/how-do-you-configure-celery-to-use-serializer-pickle